# ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have a mini ASP.NET project where I am trying to use the `Repository/UnitOfWork` architecture principle. Everything should be working as it should, however, I'm constantly encountering an issue with the dependency within my `StartUp` file. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>       InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Project.UOW.IUnitOfWork' while attempting to activate 'Project.Controllers.UsersController'.

The above error only happens when I inject IUnitOfWork as a dependency in the Startup file. If I add all three dependencies, I get a different error in the effect of =>

"HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway. The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process."

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
```

IRepository:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
{
    Task<TEntity> GetById(int id);
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll();
}
```

Repository:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
        private readonly DbContext _context;
        public Repository(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> GetById(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll()
        {
            return await _context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
        }
}
```

IUserRepository:

```
  public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
  {
        Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllUsers();
        IEnumerable<User> GetUserById(int Id);
  }
```

UserRepository:

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
{

    public UserRepository(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetUserById(int Id)
    {
        return Context.User.Where(p => p.UserId == Id).ToList();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return await Context.User.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
        private DbContext _context;

        public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            User = new UserRepository(_context); 
        }

        public IUserRepository User { get; set; }

        public int Complete()
        {
            return _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
```

}

IUnitOfWork:

```
 public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
 {
        IUserRepository User { get; set; }
        int Complete();
 }
```

Startup:

```
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

UserController:

```
 public class UsersController : Controller
 {
        private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public UsersController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        // GET: Users
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var getAllUsers = _unitOfWork.User.GetAllUsers();

            return View(await getAllUsers);
        }
}
```

Comment: your dbcontext and anything that depends on it should all be registered as scoped. The framework automatically creates a scope per web request and will dispose of the idisposables at the end of the request automatcially.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Joe. How would that look like in the Startup file? Should I just place= > services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(); and remove all others?

Comment: @ChrisH. you don't need the two transient services, since they are not really injected anywhere they are just used as type checks. Your `UnitOfWork` doesn't need to implement `IDisposable` because that's done automatically by the service at the end of the request. Your `UserRepository` is inheriting from `Repository` twice as well.

Comment: @AntonToshik that didn't seem to have worked. I have removed both transient services, and removed IDisposable from UnitOfWork. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: If you change `public UsersController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)` to `public UsersController(DbContext dbContext)` (and any other code required to make the solution compile) and run it, what error do you get?

Comment: @mjwills When I did that, I was able to successfully display a list of users to the view. The only times it didn't work was when I use this method => public UsersController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)

Comment: @mjwills So I just used IUserRepository instead of IUnitOfWork. Same issue. I have tried commenting out the 3 services, but that has not resolved the issue => services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

Comment: Could you post the your register Ioc container of the DbContext in the question?

Comment: @ToanVo I don't understand your question. Are you wanting posted?

Comment: @JoeAudette, you don't need to register Transient services as Scoped only because it is depend n scoped `DbContext`. But you could not use scoped services as a dependencies for Singleton types.

Comment: @ChrisH.I would like to see your DbContext scope which has been registered into the Microsoft Dependency Injection. It is the root cause of this bug. But I don't see it in your code. I guess you register it with Scope dependency. So UnitOfWork and Repository should be changed as a Scope as well.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seemed to have resolved it self just by starting a new project. So thank you all for helping out!